# iPhone Simulators not showing up in debug mode in Visual Studio for Mac. Xamarin.IOS

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I developed an application in Xamarin.IOS on a windows machine, but the build time is getting ridiculous. So I decided to try to load and develop the solution on my Mac using VS. I have updated everything on my Mac *(such as: Mac OSX, visual studio, and Xcode)*. I load the solution and everything builds, but no simulators show up in the target devices for debug mode. If I switch to release, the simulators show up, but not in debug. All provisioning files are downloaded and I have it set to Developer Automatic and Automatic.
Debug and Release are the only two build options. Debug|IPhoneSimulator is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

I also managed to get in this screwed up state with a new iOS project in VS4M. I tried changing various config settings to get it working, to no avail.

I added a new single-page iOS project to the same solution to see if the problem would persist. *This fixed the problem in the new product and the existing project*. I then deleted the extra project and called it good.

A stupid solution, to a stupid problem.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to choose Build Configuration Debug|iPhoneSimulator, check the configurations and the target platform

Comment: Debug|iPhoneSimulator is not an option. Only Debug or Release.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating a new project and edited the sln file to mimic what the defaults were for a new project then it started working.